# How to save resources from fullCalendar to database?

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, fullcalendar

I'm developing an event Scheduler using fullCalendar resource library with draggable events. I was able to get the events being dragged get saved in the database.

For now, the database has only one table with three columns - id(autoincrement), title,start, end.

I've just added the resource column to the calendar which also has an add rooms button on it that lets the user add the rooms himself. Here's what I've referred to built it.

For the draggable events:  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/external-dragging-demo
For the resources : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/addResource-demo

Here's my code:

main.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
var Draggable = FullCalendarInteraction.Draggable;
var containerEl = document.getElementById('external-events');
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var checkbox = document.getElementById('drop-remove');

new Draggable(containerEl, {
itemSelector: '.fc-event',
eventData: function(eventEl) {
  return {
    title: eventEl.innerText
  };
}
});   
 var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
plugins: [ 'interaction', 'resourceTimeline' ],
header: {
   left: 'promptResource today prev,next',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek'
},
customButtons: {
promptResource: {
text: '+ room',
click: function() {
  var title = prompt('Room name');
   console.log(title);
  if (title) {
        calendar.addResource({
          title: title
        });
        fetch('add_resources.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  },
  body: encodeFormData(title)
})
         .then(response => console.log(response))
.catch(error => console.log(error));
      }

    }
  }
},

editable: true,
aspectRatio: 1.5,
defaultView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',
resources: '',
events: '',
droppable: true,
drop: function(info) {
if (checkbox.checked) {
  info.draggedEl.parentNode.removeChild(info.draggedEl);
}
  },
    eventLimit: true,
      events: "all_events.php",
      displayEventTime: false,
      eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
        if (event.allDay === 'true') {
            event.allDay = true;
        } else {
            event.allDay = false;
        }
    },
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
eventReceive: function(info) {


 var eventData = {
    title: info.event.title,
    start: moment(info.event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"),
    end: moment(info.event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
  }; 
  console.log(eventData);
  //send the data via an AJAX POST request, and log any response which comes from the server
  fetch('add_event.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      body: encodeFormData(eventData)
    })
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));

}
  });
  calendar.render();
});

const encodeFormData = (data) => {
  var form_data = new FormData();

  for ( var key in data ) {
    form_data.append(key, data[key]);
  }
  return form_data;   
}
```

index.php

```
<link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timegrid@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/interaction@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timegrid@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timeline@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/resource-timeline@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timeline@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/resource-common@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/resource-timeline@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src='main.js'></script>

<div id='external-events'>
  <p>
    <strong>Draggable Events</strong>
  </p>
  <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
  <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
  <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
  <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
  <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
  <p>
    <input type='checkbox' id='drop-remove' />
    <label for='drop-remove'>remove after drop</label>
  </p>
</div>
<div id='calendar-container'>
   <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>
```

add_resouces.php

```
<?php

require 'connection.php';
$title = $_POST['title'];
$conn = DB::databaseConnection();
$conn->beginTransaction();
$sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO Resources ( resourceTitle ) VALUES ( :title )";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlInsert);
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $title); 
if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $conn->commit();
        return true;
    } else {
        $conn->rollback();
        return false;
    }

?>
```

So I'm making another table for the resources with two columns in it - roomId and roomTitle. My question is how do I save the roomTitle into the database using the '+ room' button.

For now, the frontend for the resource column is working - i.e the room is visible on the page after I add it through that button. The event drag and drop is working too - it is getting saved to the database after being dropped on the calendar.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209889/discussion-on-question-by-aam-how-to-save-resources-from-fullcalendar-to-databas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an AJAX request after your command to add the resource to the calendar, so that you send the title data to add_resources.php.

```
customButtons: {
  promptResource: {
    text: "+ room",
    click: function() {
      var title = prompt("Room name");
      if (title) {
        calendar.addResource({
          title: title
        });
        fetch("add_resources.php", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json"
          },
          body: encodeFormData({ "title": title})
        })
          .then(response => console.log(response))
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/WNNeLNV?&editable=true&editors=001

Comment: Can you also tell exactly what do I need to change in the add_resources.php?